# Facets in Magento 2 Rest API for search. Are they available ? how do i make them available?

Tags: magento2, rest-api

How do i make facets available in Magento 2 ?
Currently i do not think it's supported in the Search Rest APIs

Answer (score 0):

Facets are now available as **aggregations** from Magento 2.3.4 onwards:

Please find documentation link here:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/graphql/queries/products.html#Aggregation